# Spring Web MVC - Controller não funcionando

Tags: java, mvc, aplicação-web, spring, jsp

Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação básica, com um controller que envia uma mensagem para a tela e colocar CSS no projeto, mas ou o CSS funciona ou o controller. Seguem os códigos:
 1) NetBeans Projects\SpringMVC\web\WEB-INF\dispatcher-servlet.xml
  http://pastebin.com/LppDiL5D 
 2) NetBeans Projects\SpringMVC\web\WEB-INF\web.xml
  http://pastebin.com/GxJDetY6
 3) SpringMVC\src\java\com\fernando\controller\IndexController.java
  http://pastebin.com/U3JZjGZF
 4) SpringMVC\web\WEB-INF\jsp\index.jsp
  http://pastebin.com/S29DjUNV
5) applicationContext.xml
  http://pastebin.com/X3703kWR

Edit:
1) NetBeans Projects\SpringMVC\web\WEB-INF\dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
      <!-- the application context definition for the springapp DispatcherServlet -->

    <!--<bean name="/index.htm" class="com.fernando.controller"/>-->


    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

2) NetBeans Projects\SpringMVC\web\WEB-INF\web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

3) SpringMVC\src\java\com\fernando\controller\IndexController.java

```
/*
 * SpringMVC
 * CopyRight Rech Informática Ltda. Todos os direitos reservados.
 */
package com.fernando.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * Descrição da classe.
 */
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    //@RequestMapping(value = "/index",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World!");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

4) SpringMVC\web\WEB-INF\jsp\index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Welcome to Spring Web MVC project</title>

              <spring:url value="/resources/css/index.css" var="mainCss" />
              <link href="${mainCss}" rel="stylesheet" />

    </head>

    <body>${message}
        <p>${message} Hello! This is the default welcome page for a Spring Web MVC project.</p>
        <p><i>To display a different welcome page for this project, modify</i>
            <tt>index.jsp</tt> <i>, or create your own welcome page then change
                the redirection in</i> <tt>redirect.jsp</tt> <i>to point to the new
                welcome page and also update the welcome-file setting in</i>
            <tt>web.xml</tt>.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

5) applicationContext.xm

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <!--bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.url}"
    p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" /-->

    <!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->

</beans>
```

Comment: Poste os códigos diretamente aqui na pergunta, e formate-os clicando em  `{}`

Comment: Ajustado conforme pedido